# How to make shortest path between two points algorithm faster?

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path

I wrote this algorithm. It works (at least with my short test cases), but takes too long on larger inputs. How can I make it faster?

```
// Returns an array of length 2 with the two closest points to each other from the
// original array of points "arr"
private static Point2D[] getClosestPair(Point2D[] arr) 
{

    int n = arr.length;

    float min = 1.0f;
    float dist = 0.0f;
    Point2D[] ret = new Point2D[2];

    // If array only has 2 points, return array
    if (n == 2) return arr;

    // Algorithm says to brute force at 3 or lower array items
    if (n <= 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
            {                   
                // If points are identical but the point is not looking 
                // at itself, return because shortest distance is 0 then 
                if (i != j && arr[i].equals(arr[j]))
                {
                    ret[0] = arr[i];
                    ret[1] = arr[j];
                    return ret;                   
                }
                // If points are not the same and current min is larger than
                // current stored distance
                else if (i != j && dist < min)
                {
                    dist = distanceSq(arr[i], arr[j]);
                    ret[0] = arr[i];
                    ret[1] = arr[j];
                    min = dist;
                }        
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    int halfN = n/2;

    // Left hand side
    Point2D[] LHS = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, halfN);
    // Right hand side
    Point2D[] RHS = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, halfN, n);

    // Result of left recursion
    Point2D[] LRes = getClosestPair(LHS);
    // Result of right recursion
    Point2D[] RRes = getClosestPair(RHS);

    float LDist = distanceSq(LRes[0], LRes[1]);
    float RDist = distanceSq(RRes[0], RRes[1]);

    // Calculate minimum of both recursive results
    if (LDist > RDist)
    {
        min = RDist;
        ret[0] = RRes[0];
        ret[1] = RRes[1];
    }
    else
    {
        min = LDist;
        ret[0] = LRes[0];
        ret[1] = LRes[1];       
    }


    for (Point2D q : LHS)
    {
        // If q is close to the median line
        if ((halfN - q.getX()) < min)
        {
            for (Point2D p : RHS)
            {
                // If p is close to q
                if ((p.getX() - q.getX()) < min)
                {               
                    dist = distanceSq(q, p);        
                    if (!q.equals(p) && dist < min)
                    {
                        min = dist;
                        ret[0] = q;
                        ret[1] = p;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private static float distanceSq(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
{
    return (float)Math.pow((p1.getX() - p2.getX()) + (p1.getY() - p2.getY()), 2);
}
```

I am loosely following the algorithm explained here: http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairDQ.html

and a different resource with pseudocode here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJRi4.png

I cannot change the return type of the function, or add any new arguments.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - cut the time by a vast amount. The `distanceSq` function is wrong. Best to use Java's Point2D `somepoint.distanceSq(otherpoint);` method instead.

As for the original brute force when `n` is 3 (it will only ever be 3 or 2 in that scenario), a linear search is better and more effective.

The checks against the `min` variable are also wrong in the inner `for` loops after the brute force condition. Using squared distance is fine, but `min` is not squared. It has preserved, original distance, which means that `min` must be square rooted in both checks (once in the outer loop, once in the inner for each check).

So,

```
if ((p.getX() - q.getX()) < min)
```

Should be

```
if ((p.getX() - q.getX()) < Math.sqrt(min))
```

Same goes for the other check.

Thanks for your answers everyone!

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do.

First, you can very simply cut the time the program takes to run by changing the second iteration to run only on the "reminder" points. This helps you to avoid calculating both `(i,j)` and `(j,i)` for each values. To do so, simply change:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
```

This will still be `O(n^2)` though.

You can achieve `O(nlogn)` time by iterating the points, and storing each in a smart data structure ([kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) most likely). Before each insertion, find the closest point already stored in the DS (the kd-tree supports this in `O(logn)` time), and it is your candidate for minimal distance.

Comment: My TA says that the basic operation that should have how many times its executed reduced is the following line:
`if ((p.getX() - q.getX()) < min)`
I've already added an early exit when `min = 0` and implemented your suggestion, but it only shaves off a few milliseconds at most. Any further ideas?

Comment: Few milliseconds from what? What time is it currently taking, and what are you trying to get. Like I said, to get a real asymptotic improvement - you should use a k-d tree.

Comment: There's a cap of 2 seconds. Apparently it should be able to get through a test case of 100 000 in under that time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the linked algorithm mentions sorting the array by one coordinate so that given LHS q in point 1 to 2000, if RHS p at point 200 is more than 'min' distance away with only its x distance, you can avoid checking the remaining 201 to 2000 points.